# Unable to cover few lines in Test class

Tags: apex, controller, code-coverage, failing-tests

Apex Controller:

```
public class Controller{
@AuraEnabled
public static string createTask(String BankID){

    List<Bank__c> ls = new List<Bank__c>();        
    System.debug('>>>'+BankID);
     ls =  [SELECT Id, Name, BankStatus__c
           FROM Bank__c 
           where Id = :BankID
           and IsActiveFlag__c=: true 
           and BankCompleteFlag__c=: true               
           ORDER BY BankStatus__c];               

    user u = [SELECT contactId, contact.AccountId FROM user WHERE id=:userinfo.getUserId()];        

    Account a = new Account();
    a = [SELECT name, Executive_Name__c, Assigned_PCS__r.id  FROM Account WHERE id =:u.contact.AccountId ];

    Task t = new Task();
     if(ls.size() > 0 && a != null && (ls[0].BankStatus__c == 'Application' || ls[0].BankStatus__c == 'In Processing' ))
     {              
          t.OwnerId = a.Assigned__r.id;
          t.Subject = 'Test 1';
     }

     else{         
          t.OwnerId = a.Executive_Name__c;
          t.Subject = 'Test 2';
     }     
            t.Status = 'Open';
            t.Priority = 'Normal';                
            t.WhatId = Bankid;
            t.ActivityDate = Date.Today();                
            t.WhoId = u.ContactId;    
            insert t;
       return t.id;                      
    }   
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public with sharing class ControllerTest{
 @isTest Static void createTaskTest()
    {
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='ProfileName'];
        UserRole UR=[Select Id from UserRole where Name='RoleName'];        
        String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
        Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
        String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;
        User u = new User(Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23),  email = uniqueName + '@test1' + orgId + '.org',
                              Username = uniqueName + '@test1' + orgId + '.org', 
                              EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Tester', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                              LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, userroleid=UR.ID, 
                              TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles');
        insert u;            
        system.runAs(u)
        {            
            Account a = new Account(
                Name='lAccount',                
                Assigned__c=u.Id,
                );
            insert a;
            Contact contact = new Contact(
                LastName='LastName', 
                AccountId = a.Id);
            insert contact;       
            Bank__c BankInsert = new Bank__c(IsActiveFlag__c= true, BankCompleteFlag__c= true, BankStatus__c ='In Processing');
            List<Bank__c> BankList = new List<Bank__c>();
            BankList.add(BankInsert);
        /*Modified*/
        insert BankList; 
        string BankId = BankList[0].Id;

       Test.startTest();           
           Controller.CreateTask(BankId);
       Test.stopTest();
        }
   }
}
```

The test run is not covering the controller from Task t = new Task();
I get this **System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject** Error. Not sure if I am passing the List value correctly. Can someone help me on this, thanks.

/**********this Code is working***********/

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=True)
    public Static void createTaskTest()
    {
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Profilename'];
        UserRole UR=[Select Id from UserRole where Name='Rolename'];        
        String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
        Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
        String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;        
        User u = [SELECT id from User where ContactId =: System.Label.Con_Id];      
        Contact c = [SELECT id, AccountId from Contact where Id =: System.Label.Con_Id ];       
        system.runAs(u)
        {            
            Bank__c BankInsert = new Bank__c(IsActiveFlag__c= true, BankCompleteFlag__c= true, BankStatus__c ='Processing', Con__c = c.Id,
                                                     Par__c = c.AccountId);
            List<Bank__c> BankList = new List<Bank__c>();
            BankList.add(BankInsert);
            insert BankList; 
            string BankId = BankList[0].Id;

            Test.startTest();       
               PipeLineController.CreateTask(BankId);
            Test.stopTest();
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Is the code complete? This shouldn't even compile, you're not passing `Controller.CreateTask()` anything

Comment: The unit test is telling you that your code isn't working. Fix your code first before you worry about the unit test.

Comment: Yes, I am passign `List<Bank__c> Bank1 = Controller.CreateTask();`

Comment: My Code works perfectly, Tasks are being assigned correctly. Query returns the values too.

Comment: The inconsistency in your formatting and variable name/case is annoying to read, if you update it to be more legible you may get more help.  And no, this makes no sense to me `List<Bank__c> Bank1 = Controller.CreateTask();`  that method returns a `String`, your assigning it to a `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though your class is looking for an `Account` (and `Contact`) associated with the running user.

However, in the unit test you are not setting the `ContactId` of your recently created contact on the user.  This is what is causing the query to run no rows.

Comment: Thanks George, is there any better way to write this test class, thanks.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help George, I modified my code and was able to fix the error.

Answer (score -2):

create account and contact first  then user have field contactId=con.id to  be assigned  mark if you got your answer thanks